# I want a UITableView inside of a UIScrollView to extend to the bottom of the UIScrollView and not get cut off by initial screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

so I have a viewcontroller that I put a scrollview in. Inside the scrollview, I put a bunch of items in the top half, like an image, labels, and buttons. On the bottom half, I put a uitableview. I set all the constraints and everything.
I used the following code:

```
let bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let w:Int  = Int(bounds.size.width)
let h:Int = Int(chaptersTableView.contentSize.height)
let temp: Int = 300 + h
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: w, height: temp)
chaptersTableView.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 280.5, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(44 * sampleModel.objectChapterList.count))
```

I wanted to set the contentsize of the scrollview, and then set the height of my tableview frame.

The tableview is meant to contain many items, so I want the user to be able to scroll down, and the entire contents of the scrollview to scroll down to reveal more of the tableview. However, the tableview always gets cut off and when I scroll down in the scrollview, the table ends. I have to scroll inside of the tableview to access more cells.

Even when I replace the "44 * (number of cells in my table)" with a random number like 100, it will at first cut the table off so that is it short, but then when I tap the screen, the table will change to resume being full length to the bottom of the screen (but not to bottom of scrollview).

I thought about making all the stuff in the top half of the scrollview just another cell of the tableview so that it can be part of the table and I can avoid this hassle, but that would be a lot of work so I wanted to see if I could do this.

If you need pictures or something, I can provide them. If I'm not being clear, make sure to comment and I can explain better.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? This is pretty easy with autolayout.

Comment: why are you using scrollview @Ethan Zhao

Comment: @VinodKumar so that I can scroll down the page and have the top of the page go down with the tableview.

Comment: @Dima yes I am using autolayout

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you to use tableView only. You can create your top view in the header of tableView. Doing this there will be no need to maintain the content size of scrollView.

Comment: huh, I see. However, I am already using the header of the tableview to display a label. Would I be able to keep that if I did this?

Comment: It is the good way to manage the view in Table header or in Section header, as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

When two scrollable views with the same direction are put to each other, it always cause problems. I think in your case would be better to place only `UITableView` on  the screen: you can whether place `UITableView` within another non-scrollable view, that holds you static content, our put your static content as a header for `UITableView`. Let me know if you need me to elaborate the idea. Hope, it'll help.

Comment: I think what Ethan wants is for only *one* of them to scroll. He wants the tableview to be completely expanded to fit its contents and only the scrollview to scroll.

Comment: I got it, But I can't see anything that require UIScrollView at all here. Using a single scrollable view would be easier, wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see. However, I already have a header for the tableview that is a label. Would I be able to keep that if I were to put everything in the header?

Comment: @EthanZhao, I suppose that you have header for section of the UITableView, not the UITableView itself. So, yes, you can easily add header for the UITableView without having changed the label for your section.

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev hi, I did it and it worked! Thanks so much! I'm an idiot lol... it was so simple all along and I went such a hard route...

Answer (score 2):

i think you should do this:

first: (see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81895)

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
 tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
 tableView.rowHeight = 70`

then

`tableView.frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height`

Comment: It worked great and I have custom view above UITableView. Both inside UIScrollView. Only added 
`tableView.isScrollEnabled = false`

Comment: This works well if you don't want to use the 'all with a tableview solution', I did dont set the rowHeight however.. let it calculate itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is to add a static table in a `UIScrollView`. As far as I know, a `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which means you are putting a `UIScrollView` into another one. This might cause the scrolling to have weird behaviours.

If you have already calculated the content size and set the table frame size, maybe you can try disabling the scroll property of the table view using the following code:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Tell me how it goes :)

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but the table still gets cut off at the end of the initial screen

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but mine just worked fine. Can you provide a photo of the "cut off" you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I realized that whenever I set the frame of the tableView with `X` or `Y` larger than `0`, the right part or bottom part of the table will be cut by scrollView. I compensate the area that has been cut by setting `scrollView.contentInset` property and it was fixed. For example, you have the `Y` value set as `280.5`, so add this to your code: `scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 280.5, 0)`. The four values are `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` respectively, meaning the space (margin) for the scroll view. Keep me updated with the outcome :)

Comment: Hmm.. I can't really tell what is cutting the table. Did you calculate the table height correctly(including header height)? Btw, I got it working without setting the `scrollView.contentSize` property.

Comment: How did you set up the stuff in your uiscrollview? Was there stuff on top and then a uitablrview on the bottom?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141331/discussion-between-firemango-and-ethan-zhao).